# Spring mvc from doesn't call controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller

I'm new using spring framework and I'm just creating my own project in order to catch the idea. The flow of this is loging -> customer list -> select one cusstomer -> Pet list.
I have a button on first page with a form in order to add a customer and  it is working properly. However, similar code to a second button in pet page to add a pet is not working. When I try to save the new pet, it is returning HTTP 400 – Bad Request and nothing in the console

pet-form.jsp :

```
 <form:form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pet/savePet"
                modelAttribute="pet" method="POST">

                <!-- need to associate this data with customer id -->
                <form:hidden path="owner.id" />
    ......
    <td><input type="submit" value="Save" class="save" /></td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

PetController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/pet")
public class PetController {
.....

    @PostMapping("/savePet")
    public String savePet(@ModelAttribute("pet") Pet thePet) {
        System.out.println("New Pet " + thePet.toString());

        thePet.setOwner(customerService.getCustomer(thePet.getOwner().getId()));

        System.out.println("Controller" + thePet);
        // save the customer using our service
        petService.savePet(thePet);

        return "redirect:/pet/showListPets";
    }
```

Any ideas what is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the page within the browser and seeing what `action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/pet/savePet"` resolves to?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean with "inspecting the page" ?

Comment: Depending on which browser you're using, something along the lines of right click > Inspect Element (in Safari for example) to view all the elements on the web page, so you can see what the action path resolves to. You should be able to google "[Browser name] inspect element" to find how to do it with whatever browser you're using.

Comment: Hi, it is resolving to action="/crm-with-security-jdbc-encryption-authentication/pet/savePets" method="POST">
It match with the controller, so , I'm not sure what's the problem..

Comment: That doesn't look like it lines up with the path that you're expecting for your controller, right? Try removing the `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` portion and see if it resolves to the correct path

Comment: Sorry, I copied wrong and edited the comments, it is :<form id="pet" action="/crm-with-security-jdbc-encryption-authentication/pet/savePets" method="POST">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my question, however I dont understand why, so , if someone is so kind to explain me.. better :)
The problem was solved adding BindingResult paramenter to the controller method :

```
@PostMapping("/savePets")
    public String savePets(@ModelAttribute("pet") Pet thePet, BindingResult result) {
```

Thanks